# When you use jQuery .removeClass() does it return an error when run on an element that does not have that class?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have four html elements that when clicked I want to have a specific class applied to. The problem is that that class is only for one of the four at any one time. I want to when one element is clicked have that class removed from the other three elements and applied to the one that was clicked. If I were to run a loop that removed that class from every single element before applying that class to the element clicked would there be an error on the elements that did not have that class?

Comment: dude, no there won't be any problem. Jquery takes care of null check. If you have class it will do it otherwise it won't do it.

Comment: @gov great, thanks. You should post your comment as an answer so I can mark you as the answer.

Comment: @gov great I will mark you as the answer once the 15 mins go by :(

Comment: @RightSaidFred I thought about that but I thought maybe it might not have an error but it might not be the correct or easiest way to go about it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

@chrome dude, no there won't be any problem. Jquery takes care of null check. If you have class it will do it otherwise it won't do it.

Answer (score 4):

No.  The `removeClass()` function returns jQuery (the same jQuery object it was invoked on) and won't do anything if the class isn't present.     You really only need to remove the class from the element that has it, though.

```
$('a').click( function() {
    $('a.foo-class').removeClass('foo-class');
    $(this).addClass('foo-class');
});
```

Comment: the thing is that it is not positive which element has that class already.

Comment: @chromedude - The example assumes you are only using anchor tags.  If you are using something else or additional tags or the class is specific to only the elements you care about, omit the tag selector and use only the class selector.  There's no need to loop over elements that don't have the class.

Comment: @tvanfosson I did that but it does not seem to work. Here is the code: http://goo.gl/8j8YG

Comment: @chromedude - your example was using MooTools, not JQuery.  Try switching it to jQuery.  Once I did that it worked for me. MooTools has a different interpretation of the $ function/selectors.  It's certainly doable with MooTools, but not with the code above.

Comment: @tvanfosson thanks so much, I am not sure how I forgot to switch that.

Answer (score 3):

No.